# Angular Material Not Locked sidebar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I've a sidebar like this:

[image]
      
                Button 1
                Button 2
            
            
                
                    This Starter Application consists of a Toolbar, SideNav (with two buttons), and Content area.

This is the content area!

**Current Behaviour** - when i remote the `md-is-locked-open` attribute and start to show the sidebar if the user clicks a button, then the side bar is fullscreen and not inside the content area.

[image]
So it differs in the following points form the locked version:

- Its over the toolbar
- It grays ot the main content
- its over the content area

**Required Behaviour** - what do i have to change to have it inside the content area? So it looks exactly the sameway like it is when its locked .

- It should be unter the toolbar
- Should not overlap main content (just move it to the right=
- Should not gray out other content

Codepen [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvVJMx)

Comment: you wanna when user click a button then the sidebar change to fullscreen?

Comment: No i want to have it the sameway like it is when its locked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the:

```
<div layout="row" flex>
```

above the sidenav for:

```
<md-content layout="row" flex>
```

and the corresponding closing tag. And that's it!

The md-toolbar must be sibling to an md-content to get the behaviour you are looking for.

**EDIT**

For your further requirements please check this Codepen I've made. It does exactly what you want (override the sidenav behaviour to hide the overlay and push the contents to the right): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjXYMa

Comment: tahts only half way :-( It still greys out the main content and is lying over the content i'd like to have it expanded the sameway like locked in

Comment: Do you want the sidenav to push the content to the right?

Comment: yes so that it just looks like it is locked and it should not gray out the other contents

Comment: This feature isn't in the specs of the sidenav widget. I would suggest that you create your own panel, put it sibling to the md-content, and animate it's width by toggling a class. Overriding the behaviour of widgets is complicated and prone to be broken on future versions.

Comment: The class 'md-locked-open' is what pushes the content to the right. The backdrop can be hidden by setting it display:none. As it's sibling to the md-content, just give a class to it (for example: alterated) and make a css rule: md-content.alterated md-backdrop { display:none }

Comment: Take a look at this Codepen. It does exactly what you want (override the sidenav behaviour): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWzeKy   I had a little erron in the previous.

Comment: perfect can you post it as an answer or edit your answer then i'll accept it as solution :)

Comment: I've edited the answer and I've have corrected a little error on the codepen, now it's working as you want. Glad to help you! Please, check the answer as accepted, not just upvote!